# Auto complete codeigniter issues

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete

I want to ask question, why the auto complete does'nt changing dynamicaly when i type a keyword ? it only show all datas.
---- Controller ------

```
function control_areas(){
$term = $this->input->get('term', TRUE);
$brands = $this->dashboard_model->get_areas($term);
echo json_encode($brands);
}
```

---- Model ----

```
function get_areas($term){
$this->db->like('brand_name', $term, 'after');
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_brand');
return $query->result(); 
}
```

---- Script -----

```
$(function(){
var $sfield = $('‪#‎autocomplete‬').autocomplete({
source: function(request, response){
var url = "<?php echo site_url('dashboard/control_areas'); ?>";
$.post(url, {data:request.term}, function(data){
response($.map(data, function(brands) {
return {
value: brands.brand_name
};
}));
}, "json"); 
},
minLength: 2,
autofocus: true
});
```

---- view -----

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="brand-name" placeholder="Enter text here" class="full text"/>
```

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/4bi0jjax1/Untitled.png screenshoot

Comment: http://s2.postimg.org/odg8aatkp/Untitled.png another

Comment: i think there were some errors in in your js

Comment: fix what? You really haven't isolated a problem